# How to parse xml with duplicate xml tag names and multiple conditions using Stax parser only?

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, stax

I am trying to parse the value of Text element but as you can see, i have multiple Text elements both in myNote and yourNote. How can i parse these Text values using Stax xml parser? Plz help!!! I need this by using Stax parser only.

```
public class StaxParser {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        String fileName = "/Users/ragnar/Documents/tweet.xml";
        parseXML(fileName);

    }

    private static void parseXML(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {
        StaxHelper st = new StaxHelper();
        XMLInputFactory xmlInputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
        try {
            XMLEventReader xmlEventReader = xmlInputFactory
                    .createXMLEventReader(new FileInputStream(fileName));
            while (xmlEventReader.hasNext()) {
                XMLEvent xmlEvent = xmlEventReader.nextEvent();
                if (xmlEvent.isStartElement()) {
                    StartElement startElement = xmlEvent.asStartElement();
                    if (startElement.getName().getLocalPart().equals("MyNote")) {
                        xmlEvent = xmlEventReader.nextTag();
                        xmlEvent = xmlEventReader.nextEvent();
                        if (xmlEvent.asCharacters().getData().equals("1")) {
                            System.out.println("Number is: " + xmlEvent.asCharacters().getData());
                            // Need to set myNote1 if Number is 1
                            // Need to set myNote2 if Number is 2
                            // Need to set myNote3 if Number is 3
                            // Need to set yourNote1 if Number is 1
                            // Need to set yourNote2 if Number is 2
                            // Need to set yourNote3 if Number is 3
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (xmlEvent.isEndElement()) {
                    EndElement endElement = xmlEvent.asEndElement();
                    if (endElement.getName().getLocalPart().equals("Tweet")) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (XMLStreamException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

//StaxHelper Class

```
public class StaxHelper {

    String myNote1;
    String myNote2;
    String myNote3;
    String yourNote1;
    String yourNote2;
    String yourNote3;

    public String getMyNote1() {
        return myNote1;
    }

    public void setMyNote1(String myNote1) {
        this.myNote1 = myNote1;
    }

    public String getMyNote2() {
        return myNote2;
    }

    public void setMyNote2(String myNote2) {
        this.myNote2 = myNote2;
    }

    public String getMyNote3() {
        return myNote3;
    }

    public void setMyNote3(String myNote3) {
        this.myNote3 = myNote3;
    }

    public String getYourNote1() {
        return yourNote1;
    }

    public void setYourNote1(String yourNote1) {
        this.yourNote1 = yourNote1;
    }

    public String getYourNote2() {
        return yourNote2;
    }

    public void setYourNote2(String yourNote2) {
        this.yourNote2 = yourNote2;
    }

    public String getYourNote3() {
        return yourNote3;
    }

    public void setYourNote3(String yourNote3) {
        this.yourNote3 = yourNote3;
    }
}
```

```html
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Tweet>
 <MyNotes>
  <MyNote>
   <Number>1</Number>
   <Text>myNote1</Text>
  </MyNote>
  <MyNote>
   <Number>2</Number>
   <Text>myNote2</Text>
  </MyNote>
  <MyNote>
   <Number>3</Number>
   <Text>myNote3</Text>
  </MyNote>
 </MyNotes>
 <YourNotes>
  <YourNote>
   <Number>1</Number>
   <Text>yourNote1</Text>
  </YourNote>
  <YourNote>
   <Number>2</Number>
   <Text>yourNote2</Text>
  </YourNote>
  <YourNote>
   <Number>3</Number>
   <Text>yourNote3</Text>
  </YourNote>
 </YourNotes>
</Tweet>
```

`

Comment: Could you please provide a short summary of your question in  plain english? I don't want to debug your code only to understand what your question is about.

Comment: I am trying to parse the value of <Text> element but as you can see, i have multiple <Text> elements both in <myNote> and <yourNote>. How can i parse these <Text> values using Stax xml parser? Is it clear? if not, plz let me know. Thanks

Comment: Anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 0):

- I came up with this solution but as you can see i have too many nested if else conditions. I want a better solution than this. Note: I know Switch statement is much faster performance wise but i am restricted to use Java 1.6 version and therefore I can't use Switch for Strings.

```js
private static void parseXML(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {
  StaxHelper st = new StaxHelper();
  XMLInputFactory xmlInputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
  try {
   XMLEventReader xmlEventReader = xmlInputFactory.createXMLEventReader(new FileInputStream(fileName));
   while (xmlEventReader.hasNext()) {
    XMLEvent xmlEvent = xmlEventReader.nextEvent();
    if (xmlEvent.isStartElement()) {
     StartElement startElement = xmlEvent.asStartElement();
     if (startElement.getName().getLocalPart().equals("MyNote")) {
      xmlEvent = xmlEventReader.nextTag();
      xmlEvent = xmlEventReader.nextEvent();
      if (xmlEvent.asCharacters().getData().equals("1")) {
       String number1 = xmlEvent.asCharacters().getData();
       if (number1.equals("1")) {
        xmlEvent = xmlEventReader.nextEvent();
        xmlEvent = xmlEventReader.nextTag();
        if (xmlEvent.isStartElement() == true) {
         xmlEvent = xmlEventReader.nextEvent();
         st.setMyNote1(xmlEvent.asCharacters().getData());
         System.out.println("My Note 1 is: " + st.getMyNote1());
        } 
       } 
      } else if (xmlEvent.asCharacters().getData().equals("2")) {
       String number2 = xmlEvent.asCharacters().getData();
       if (number2.equals("2")) {
        xmlEvent = xmlEventReader.nextEvent();
        xmlEvent = xmlEventReader.nextTag();
        if (xmlEvent.isStartElement() == true) {
         xmlEvent = xmlEventReader.nextEvent();
         st.setMyNote2(xmlEvent.asCharacters().getData());
         System.out.println("My Note 2 is: " + st.getMyNote2());
        } 
       }
      } else if (xmlEvent.asCharacters().getData().equals("3")) {
       String number3 = xmlEvent.asCharacters().getData();
       if (number3.equals("3")) {
        xmlEvent = xmlEventReader.nextEvent();
        xmlEvent = xmlEventReader.nextTag();
        if (xmlEvent.isStartElement() == true) {
         xmlEvent = xmlEventReader.nextEvent();
         st.setMyNote3(xmlEvent.asCharacters().getData());
         System.out.println("My Note 3 is: " + st.getMyNote3());
        } 
       }
      } 
     }
     if (startElement.getName().getLocalPart().equals("YourNote")) {
      xmlEvent = xmlEventReader.nextTag();
      xmlEvent = xmlEventReader.nextEvent();
      if (xmlEvent.asCharacters().getData().equals("1")) {
       String number1 = xmlEvent.asCharacters().getData();
       if (number1.equals("1")) {
        xmlEvent = xmlEventReader.nextEvent();
        xmlEvent = xmlEventReader.nextTag();
        if (xmlEvent.isStartElement() == true) {
         xmlEvent = xmlEventReader.nextEvent();
         st.setYourNote1(xmlEvent.asCharacters().getData());
         System.out.println("Your Note 1 is: " + st.getYourNote1());
        } 
       } 
      } else if (xmlEvent.asCharacters().getData().equals("2")) {
       String number2 = xmlEvent.asCharacters().getData();
       if (number2.equals("2")) {
        xmlEvent = xmlEventReader.nextEvent();
        xmlEvent = xmlEventReader.nextTag();
        if (xmlEvent.isStartElement() == true) {
         xmlEvent = xmlEventReader.nextEvent();
         st.setYourNote2(xmlEvent.asCharacters().getData());
         System.out.println("Your Note 2 is: " + st.getYourNote2());
        } 
       }
      } else if (xmlEvent.asCharacters().getData().equals("3")) {
       String number3 = xmlEvent.asCharacters().getData();
       if (number3.equals("3")) {
        xmlEvent = xmlEventReader.nextEvent();
        xmlEvent = xmlEventReader.nextTag();
        if (xmlEvent.isStartElement() == true) {
         xmlEvent = xmlEventReader.nextEvent();
         st.setYourNote3(xmlEvent.asCharacters().getData());
         System.out.println("Your Note 3 is: " + st.getYourNote3());
        } 
       }
      } 
     }
    }

    if (xmlEvent.isEndElement()) {
     EndElement endElement = xmlEvent.asEndElement();
     if (endElement.getName().getLocalPart().equals("Tweet")) {
      break;
     }
    }
   }

  } catch (XMLStreamException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
```

Comment: Just realized, i don't need the 2nd check and if statement ---> String number1 = xmlEvent.asCharacters().getData();
       if (number1.equals("1")) {}